# C# BD .mdf string de conexão

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Boa noite pessoal,
Tenho um Banco de dados .mdf em um Windows Forms e quero fazer a string de conexão dele, alguém pode me ajudar?
Minha versão do Visual Studio é a 2015 e o arquivo fica em:
C:Documentos\Visual Studio 2017\ Projects\ Projetos\ Trabalho Final POO \ Trabalho Final POO\ BD.mdf

Answer (score 1):

Podes obter a conexão através da janela **Server Explorer**.

No Server Explorer, clica em **Connect to database**. Depois, escolha a opção **Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)** e por baixo selecione o ficheiro .mdf que pretende. Preencha os passos necessários.

Depois de adicionado a base de dados que aparecerá em Data Connections dentro do Server Explorer, clique botão direito em cima da Data Connection e por fim em **Properties**.

Dentro da janela **Properties**, existe uma propriedade chamada **Connection String** e é essa a conexão que tens que usar para aceder à base de dados.

Recomendo colocar essa conexão numa Resource.

Comment: Ainda sim não consigo fazer, está dando erro nas barras:

Comment: O código é:
SqlConnection conexão = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C: \Users\tiago\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Projetos\Trabalho Final POO\Trabalho Final POO\BD.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30);

Comment: Experimenta colocar um @ antes do string. Ou seja: @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C: \Users\tiago\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Projetos\Trabalho Final POO\Trabalho Final POO\BD.mdf"

Comment: Se não funcionar põe um segundo backlash em cada backlash: "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C: \\Users\\tiago\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Projetos\\Trabalho Final POO\\Trabalho Final POO\\BD.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30);

Comment: Isto porque em C# o backlash \ é um caracter de escapatória em strings. Para usares o backlash em strings usas uma dessas duas soluções.

Comment: usando a string de conexão me deparei com o erro:

"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PAS\PAS\bin\Debug//PatAddSys.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

obs: o caminho é fictício.